# Preimage of a set under a function

Tags: undergraduate-education, functions

I am looking for suggestions about ways to introduce the *preimage* of a set under a function. My experience is that many students find it a confusing concept. The definition I use is as follows:

Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is a function, and $A\subseteq Y$, then the *preimage of* $A$ *under* $f$ is $$f^{-1}[A]=\big\{x\in X:f(x)\in A\big\}\;.$$

Note that when teaching engineering students, I use the idea of a measuring device being a mapping from a physical state space $X$ to an observation space $Y$. You can then ask the question: Given a particular measurement/reading/observation, what physical states could have generated it? This approach is inspired by Steven M. LaValle's [Sensing and Filtering: A Fresh Perspective Based on Preimages and Information Spaces](http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/~lavalle/papers/Lav11.pdf).

Comment: I would start more generally by asking how preimages and functions are related. Probably the example of $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $x \mapsto x^2$ would come up early. Does $f^{-1}[\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}]$ correspond to a *function*? Why or why not? Then I'd build out with concrete examples of this nature...

Comment: To me LaValle's approach looks like something a teacher could easily crash-and-burn with by spending too much time on jury-rigged explanations. The notation is probably the most challenging part in my opinion. As for the concept, I'd just say it's the least many (minimal set of) things in $X$ needed to obtain all the outputs represented by $A.$ Also, I wouldn't use $A$ for a subset of $Y.$ I'd use $A$ for a subset of $X$ and $B$ for a subset of $Y.$

Comment: Why not just do it the completely abstract way? I paint sets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ for $f \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ on the whiteboard with arrows showing the mapping (different colors help), it is natural to ask what a subset of $\mathcal{A}$ maps to, and viceversa.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro You're wrong. $f^{-1}[A]$ is not minimal for non-injective functions $f$.

Comment: @Toscho: Ouch, I think that's the second time I've been corrected today! I wrote too quickly without thinking, and you're correct, of course, as the simplest examples show (a constant function). More correct would be to say that its all the things in $X$ with an output in $A$ and only those things.

Comment: The inverse image, under the "exam" mapping, of the set of sufficient grades will be the set of students who have passed the course. I think that's easy enough to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have thought about this a lot and, specifically, have wondered about the effects of terminology and notation. I'm not sure if there is a *best* answer, but here are some of my thoughts:

- When I introduce image/preimage in an intro to proofs course, I avoid using the $f^{-1}$ notation, stressing for the students that we don't want to presume $f$ has an inverse. I understand this notation is fairly standard later on and elsewhere, but before a student really understands inverse functions, I think it's best to remove the potential opportunity to conflate these two completely different concepts that happen to share notation.
- A professor of mine used "push-forward" and "pull-back" to refer to "image" and "preimage" and, the more I think about it, the more I really like those terms and want to use them (almost) exclusively myself. They really convey the *operational* aspect of the definitions: there's a function that does something, and we care about where it *pushes* domain elements (for the image) or where it *pulls back* to domain elements (for the preimage). Perhaps using these two terms in tandem with the standard terms will really tie the ideas together more coherently for students.
- I like your example about measurements and observations, but I would recommend using even *simpler* examples, both of the arbitrary/abstract and applied varieties. Specifically, use some examples to show "surprising" behavior of the preimage operator. For instance, you can construct quickly (with students' help, even) a toy example to show that "the preimage of an image of a set is not necessarily equal to the starting set". Draw some schematic diagrams with dots and arrows. Then, draw a graph of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and ask about preimages of certain intervals on the $y$-axis: Where are all the $x$-values whose output "lands in" this set? (You could use this to introduce the idea from topology that a function is continuous when "the pull-back of an open set is open".)
- Generally, as many examples as possible is, I think, the only way to really get used to this. Make sure some homework problems address these concepts. Make sure students have to "compute" preimages of certain sets, given a function, but also make sure they have to *construct their own examples*. Make them come up with a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^{-1}[\mathbb{N}]=\varnothing$, say. Depending on the specific interests of your students (computer science, engineering, math) you can tailor some more examples/exercises.

Comment: I treat relations first, and define functions as particular relations. The "inverse" I stress is just the transpose of the function as a relation in this.

Comment: Regarding the $f^{-1}$ notation, I thought it was typical in 2nd and 3rd year (U.S.) transition courses to study relations in general before specializing to functions. When this is done, $f^{-1}$ always stands for the inverse relation, which may or may not be a function.

Comment: @vonbrand: Indeed, as do I. But remember that students come out of high school with an ingrained notion of what an inverse function is, using $f^{-1}$ all over the place. However, abstract relations, images, and preimages are very new to them. I think it's, understandably, incredibly difficult for them to simultaneously synthesize all these new ideas with their old understandings and notation.

Comment: Might it help to use $f^{\text{pre}}$ or something similar as an alternative to $f^{-1}$?

Comment: @JW I learned the notation $f^-$ as a way to make a difference to the preknowledge $f^{-1}$.

Comment: @JW and Toscho: I've seen $f^{\rightarrow}$ for image sets and $f^{\leftarrow}$ for inverse image sets, both for functions and for relations.

Comment: @Dave I can't say I've ever had any experience with such a course as the *first* experience a student has with general functions.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping between reality and observation demands a high level of *scientific* abstraction, that *math* students in such a course might not have. It's possibly easier to use physical (or other scientific) laws in the form of equations between values.

For example $U$-$I$-relationship in NTCs: Should this be a function $U(I)$ or a function $I(U)$? Physics can't give an answer, so Math should deal with both. But the relation is not injective, so how to deal about it?

Comment: Do I assume correctly that by NTC you're referring to a Negative Temperature Coefficient thermistor, where $I$ is current and $U$ (or $V$) is voltage?

Comment: @JW Yes, you assume correctly.